# force user to select a content type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, content

I have a library "Accounting" and it has 12 different content type. I dont to set any default content type (looks like thats not possible). user must select a specific content type. how do i implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to edit the library new button in library settings. Uncheck the visible check box for the content type you do not want end users to use.

[image]
[image]
[image]